# Java Socket/Serversocket Internet Connection

Tags: java, sockets, networking

[Java Socket/Serversocket WAN Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317577/java-socket-serversocket-wan-connection?rq=1)

The above link already has the (exact same) question asked  and although the user there said he got the problem solved, I'm not able to do so.

Even though I have forwarded the correct port to the correct private host ip (my lappy ip) in my router settings, and used the correct public (my) router ip on the client side, I get the **connection timed out exception** (stack trace is almost the same as his/hers). What could be the problem? Could it be that my ISP blocks incoming connections as it doesn't want me to run any home servers?

The user there says, "I wasn't port forwarding the external ports correctly" at the end. What does that mean?

It works for localhost and local ip. I've configured my network settings only to use static ips to aid port-forwarding, disabled firewalls, used 2222, 60000 ports which worked well for localhost. And still my friend in another location far off (different network) could not connect.

Comment: Have you used `http://www.canyouseeme.org/` to try and see if that port is actually opened. (You must have your server running)

Comment: I just did. It says success on 60000. ISP isn't blocking. Sigh. Thank you. At least I came to know it wasn't the isp.

Comment: Then if it works it might be a problem with the other person's connection.

Comment: Okay, I tried running the client code on my lappy which was running the server but not through the localhost. I used my router's ip, the public one. It should run right? It gave the same error.

Comment: So you ran the client and server on the same computer? It might not work then due to some issues with just doing that... you must use `localhost` if you are on the same computer and `public ip` if on different